# TypePerf command not working with -s remote switch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am having two similar issues. On my local machine the `/s` command returns no valid counters if I use the ip address but works if I use the machine name. 
the more important issue is I can not get the stats of remote pc's with the ip address or the pc name. all are win 7 two on one domain and a third on a workgroup
here is what i typed on the command prompt:

```
c:>typeperf "\processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"  "\Memory\
Committed Bytes"  "\Process(_Total)\Thread Count"  "\memory\Available KBytes" "\
LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space" /s 192.168.1.13 /sc 5 /si 1


Error: No valid counters.
```

I read in another answer here to use `%%` but I think that is when it is in a bat file.

```
  c:>typeperf "\processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time"  "\Memory\
    Committed Bytes"  "\Process(_Total)\Thread Count"  "\memory\Available KBytes" "\
    LogicalDisk(C:)\%% Free Space" /s 192.168.1.13 /sc 5 /si 1

Error: No valid counters.
```

Answer (score 0):

> No valid counters

From my experience this means either there is something wrong with the definition of your counters OR you have a permission problem.

First of all it should be `-s` not `/s`.

Then you have to use a configuration file if you want to add multiple counters.
Create a plaint text file e.g. ctr.cfg and add one counter per line like this:

```
\processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
\Memory\Committed Bytes  
\Process(_Total)\Thread Count  
\memory\Available KBytes
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space
```

then call:

```
typeperf -s 1.2.3.4 -cf ctr.cfg
```